# Tensorboard profiler is trying to use the wrong version of libcupti

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

So I'm trying to set up a GPU profiler on tensorboard but I am getting this error:

```
 W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.11.2'; dlerror: libcupti.so.11.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This makes sense because the libcupti version I have is 11.6, so it's trying to get 11.2 and I don't have it. How can I specify to use `libcupti.so.11.6`?

**Machine specifications:**

- CUDA version: 11.6
- python: 3.7.1
- tensorflow: 2.8.0
- tensorboard-plugin-profile:2.5.0

Comment: I'm sure someone will know an answer but for me, the solution is usually just trying to reinstall and uninstall drivers until it works. TF and CUDA versioning has been a black art for me.

Comment: TensorFlow 2.8 doesn't support CUDA 11.6. [The latest supported version is 11.2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TensorFlow 2.8 doesn't support CUDA 11.6. but requires 11.2 [see docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

Seems you need to get in touch with the VM's owner to update the dependencies

Comment: Ahhh I see, that makes more sense. Thank you!